# IsChecked not binding properly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, checkbox

I have a list that I bind to an itemsControl. The first items bind well be not the isChecked part.

Here is the code

```
var LstTemplates = Templates.Select(x=>new {TName=x.TemplateName,TId = x.Id, IsLinked = IsLinked(x.Id)});
itemsControlTemplates.ItemsSource = LstTemplates;
```

IsLinked is a function that returns a boolean

```
private bool IsLinked(int Id)
{
   return (AnotherList.Any(x=>x.id==Id));
}
```

In the XAML

```
<CheckBox CommandParameter="{Binding TId}" Content="{Binding TName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsLinked}" />
```

The above does not work... or rather, the app freezes and breaks on a totally unrelated code.

But if I take the same "{Binding IsLinked}" and output it to a messagebox or even to the content of checkbox, then it shows...

Where did I go wrong?

Update:
Okay, ignore the part where I said the code breaks at an unrelated code, that does misleading.

```
                  <ItemsControl Name="itemsControlTemplates" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">

                                    <CheckBox CommandParameter="{Binding TId}" Content="{Binding TName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsLinked}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

When I output 'IsLinked' to the content, it displays. How do I get it to bind to 'IsChecked'?

Comment: `or rather, the app freezes and breaks on a totally unrelated code` not enough information here to answer.  This is where writing a prototype which does exactly, and only, this can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsChecked is trying to do a TwoWay binding... I don't think this is possible on an anonymous type.

Try

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsLinked, Mode=OneWay}"
```